# Dynamic Div and external sytlesheet Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a div that I want to place within a container.  The div appears where I want it to, however; when the div appears the styling for redHeaderObject(which is contained in an external style sheet) seems to always be missing.  Is there anyway to reference the external css file and class?

```
    var redHeaderObject = $("<div class='classname'>Coding Details</div>");
  $("#dManager_draggedContainer").append("<div id='NotesDiv'>" + redHeaderObject.html() + "<div class='Notes-content'>" + NotesHTML + "</div></div>");
    $("#NotesDiv").position(
    {
        my: "left+10 top+5",
        at: "left top",
        of: $("#dManager_draggedContainer"),
        collision: "flipfit"
    }).css("height", "15px").width("90px").css("z-index", 80);
```

Comment: `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR LINK HERE">');`

Comment: @KingCoder11 Unfortunately it didn't work